# Using HtmlHelper to Dynamically generate html controls in the controller (not using Razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to generate a form controls based on an XML configuration file. In that file I have list of attributes such as controlid, class, maxlength, required, readonly..etc. I am not using Razor to generate the controls in the View. I prefer this method.

I am using the below code to generate the control.

```
IDictionary customHTMLAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();     
customHTMLAttributes.Add("class", "form-control");
                    customHTMLAttributes.Add("maxlength", field.MaxLength);
                    customHTMLAttributes.Add("minlength", field.MinLength);
                    htmlString  = helper.TextBox(field.ControlName, "", customHTMLAttributes);
```

The rendered HTML control has got some invalid data simillar to this:

```
<input Comparer=\"System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[System.String]\" Count=\"3\" Keys=\"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]\" Values=\"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]\" id=\"txtManufacturer\" name=\"txtManufacturer\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" />
```

If I use `new {attributename = value, attribute2 = value}` instead of using Dictionary to create the list of attributes, it will render the control properly.

EDIT:
My question is how to use Dictionary to create a dynamic list of attributes which will then be passed on to the `HtmlHelper.TextBox("text1","",customAttributes);`

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: When the control is rendered it has invalid attributes in it. Sorry, my question was how to use Dictionary to create a dynamic list of attributes which will then pass to the `HtmlHelper.TextBox("text1","",customAttributes);`